# How to name (reverse) values of a playback speed slider

Tags: terminology

I got a video-dialog that comes with a Playback-speed slider.

[image]

The slider holds the values

-16x, -8x, -4x, -2x, -1x, -1/2x, 1/2x, 1x, 2x, 4x, 8x, 16x

Negative values mean reversed playback.

The numbers however, do not correspond with the actual playbackspeed. A video set to 2x playback speed doesn't necessarily playback the video at twice the speed. Depended on the codec, FPS, PAL/NTSC etc. this can fluctuate.

Since we cannot solve this, we opt to change the numbers in the slider to words, similar how VLC does it:

[image]

Now it's easy to just change the numbers to "slower" "fast" "faster" and such, but i'm wondering how state the reverse speeds. Is it just "reverse slower" and "reverse fast"? Or should I use a different naming for those?

Comment: One thing worth considering is that humans don't think or perceive in terms of absolute size (this dog is 75cm tall and that dog is 55cm tall), but rather by relative size (this dog is bigger than that dog) so you are probably better off with Very fast, fast, Normal speed, Slow, Very slow.

Answer (score 1):

I think words are fine in menu like VLC does it. But if you want to have a relation between the playbackspeeds it's better do use symbols. Just a small icon-set like this one.

[image: forward and backward symbols for different playback speeds]

This are well-known symbols of the VHS era up to today.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where "reverse" is on this UI, but if it is a separate option on the menu, then it can be the same as the forward options.

Playback

- **Forward**

  - Very fast
  - fast
  - Normal speed
  - Slow
  - Very slow
- **Reverse**

  - Very fast
  - fast
  - Normal speed
  - Slow
  - Very slow

There are some good ideas in this post: [What are good rules for naming menu items?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5124/what-are-good-rules-for-naming-menu-items)

Comment: The slider is 50/50... the left side is negative (reverse) and the right side is positive (forward)

http://i.imgur.com/cM0hDAe.png

Comment: Oh - sounds potentially confusing